# msbuild custom compiler/build script

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I'm attempting to use TFS and MSBuild as a build and source control for a non-.NET project.  This project contains a series of individual called .skbsrc files, that each compile into a .skb file.  I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use MSBuild in a way to build these files.

Say I'm using the example on the msdn website:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="testfile.skbsrc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Csc Sources="@(Compile)"/>  
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Csc is clearly used for C# code, and runs the csc.exe program.  Is there a way I can make a block like this for my own compiler (skbuilder) so I could run like:

```
<Skbuilder Sources="@(Compile)" />
```

which in turn would run

```
>skbuilder testfile.skbsrc
```

If this is possible with msbuild, could anyone post an example?  I've been unable to find anything in my searches.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It sounds like you are new to MSBuild.  You could also create a dummy C# class library project, add all your skbsrc files to the project as content and then put a postbuild command in to call your compiler.  Not very elegant super easy.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a customized task in msbuild to do it. ["CSC"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/s5c8athz(v=vs.120).aspx) is a default task in C#, so what you need is to implement a similar task  for your exe.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/t9883dzc(v=vs.120).aspx) explains how to write a task for msbuild.

Comment: That's a lot of infrastructure for simply shelling out to an EXE.

Comment: but it gives a lot of control, consider you can write tasks inline (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Exec Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx).

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <SourceFiles Include="*.skbsrc"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <Exec Command="skbuilder &quot;%(SourceFiles.Identity)&quot;"/>
    </Target>

</Project>
```

You'll also need to pass an argument to your skbuilder program telling it to output it's files to the $(OutDir) directory  or use Copy Task to pick up *.skb to $(OutDir).   Use quotes around the argument incase the TFS workspace path has spaces in it.

Finally you can test this on your own machine without using TFS by creating a simple .BAT file:

```
set PATH=%CD%;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
msbuild build.proj > build.log
```